# Euclidean recursive algorithm

Tags: prolog, greatest-common-divisor, visual-prolog

Ok, I know it's really a stupid question, but I can't get it. 
There is a task where I should find a recursive algorithm of 
[Euclid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid) (gcd). I've done it for one case, here:

```
nondeterm nod (integer,integer,integer)
CLAUSES
nod (X,0,X):- !.
nod (0,X,X):- !.
nod (X,0,X):-X>0.
nod (X,Y,G):-Y>0, Z = X mod Y, nod (Y,Z,G).
```

I need to do another case, where recursion is beginnig from х0, when Xi then calling for function counting Xi+1.
It should be sort of it:

```
PREDICATES
nondeterm nod (integer,integer,integer)
nondeterm nod1 (integer,integer,integer,integer,integer)     
CLAUSES
nod(X,Y,Z):- nod1(X,Y,Z,0,0).   
nod1 (X,Y,Z,X,Y):- Otvet = Z, write("Otvet=", Otvet, "\n"), !.
nod1 (X,Y,X,Y):- nod1 (X,Y,X,Y).
nod1 (X,Y,Z,X1,Y1):-
              X1>Y1, X>0, Y>0, 
              Y2 = X1 mod Y1,
              X2 = Y1,
              nod1(X,Y,Z,X2,Y2).
```

But it doesn't work. Please, help me with that.

Comment: why nondeterm? seems deterministic to me

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question. Where is `Xi+1`?

In your first code box, `nod (X,0,X):- !.` conflicts with `nod (X,0,X):-X>0.`. The second will never be called.

This rule is useless `nod1 (X,Y,X,Y):- nod1 (X,Y,X,Y).` and would loop if called.

Comment: well... i thought cuz i need to find the result of nod. am i wrong?

Comment: Sorry, my english are bad cuz i am only usual russian girl :) i just mean that there should be two types of recursion. One acts from up to down, another - second - from down to up (if i told it in unusual way, please say me about it and i try to say it in another form). How should i stop lopping? Is there should be something, that could stop it? I don't know what it could be.

Comment: Surely you can stop (with failure) when your Xi reach X or Y

Comment: Is this a homework? Check http://en.literateprograms.org/Euclidean_algorithm_(Prolog)

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me. Please note the use of 
rem, but I guess you could also use mod:

```
% sys_gcd(+Integer, +Integer, -Integer)
sys_gcd(X, 0, X) :- !.
sys_gcd(X, Y, Z) :-
   H is X rem Y,
   sys_gcd(Y, H, Z).
```

Here are some example runs with SWI-Prolog:

```
?- sys_gcd(20,30,X).
X = 10.
?- sys_gcd(-20,30,X).
X = 10.
?- sys_gcd(20,-30,X).
X = -10.
?- sys_gcd(-20,-30,X).
X = -10.
```

If you want a particular sign of the result, you
need additional code around it.

Bye